# MP3 Metadata in Windows

Tags: python, windows, mp3, id3

How does windows know the length of an mp3 file if it's not included in the mp3 metadata?  I was searching through some files and they don't include length tagging information, but windows still knows the length.  Is there a way to access the information windows knows about a file with python?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the length of the audio part with existing informations and a formula like this:

```
AudioLength = FileLength / (Sample Rate * Channels * Bits per sample / 8)
```

Maybe this articles will help you:

- [time length of an mp3 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119404/time-length-of-an-mp3-file)
- [How can I determine the length of a .wav file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82319/how-can-i-determine-the-length-of-a-wav-file-in-c)
- [Finding the length of an mp3 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037826/finding-the-length-of-an-mp3-file)