# Can you read the length of an mp3 file in python 3 on windows 10?

Tags: python-3.x, mp3

I am currently creating a music player in python 3.3 and I have a way of opening the mp3/wav files, namely through using through 'os.startfile()', but, this way of running the files means that if I run more than one, the second cancels the first, and the third cancels the second, and so on and so forth, so I only end up running the last file. So, basically, I would like a way of reading the mp3 file length so that I can use 'time.sleep(SongLength)' between the start of each file.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
I forgot to mention, but I would prefer to do this using only pre-installed libraries, as i am hoping to publish this online as a part of a (much) larger program

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the length of an mp3 file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037826/finding-the-length-of-an-mp3-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've managed to do this Using an external module, as after ages of trying to do it without any, i gave up and used [tinytag](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tinytag/), as it is easy to install and use.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing you can do without external libraries, as far as I know. Try using [pymad](http://spacepants.org/src/pymad/).
Use it like this:

```
import mad
SongFile = mad.MadFile("something.mp3")
SongLength = SongFile.total_time()
```