# How to play mp3 in python without infinite loop?

Tags: python, mp3, infinite-loop, vlc, playback

I am writing a program which reads a string, then convert it into speech and play it as mp3.
But the program does not play the music. I have checked and find out that the mp3 file is created and can be played with standard mp3 players but not the script.
I am using gtts module (for converting text to speech) and vlc module (to play mp3)
The code is like this.Please note that 'm' is the text I want to convert to sound.

```
tts = gTTS(text=m, lang='en')
tts.save("greeting.mp3")
p = vlc.MediaPlayer("greeting.mp3")
p.play()
```

I have further found out that the mp3 plays when I provide an infinite loop after play command.Like this

```
tts = gTTS(text=m, lang='en')
tts.save("greeting.mp3")
p = vlc.MediaPlayer("greeting.mp3")
p.play()
while True:
    pass
```

Is there any way I can avoid that Infinite loop.I have already imported all the required modules to the project.

Comment: is `p.play()` the last statement in your program? If so, the problem might be that program terminates before it has a chance to play the mp3

Comment: yes i too think so... How can we fix it?

Comment: I don't know much about the vlc module you are using but It seems to have a `is_playing()` method. So, you can replace `while True:` with `while p.is_playing()` and probably replace the `pass` with a `sleep` function to avoid busy waiting

Comment: I guess there is also a `get_length()` method which returns the length in ms . You can also use it like `time.sleep(  
p.get_length()/1000.)`

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is starting a subprocess with the vlc lib, when your program closes, it closes the subprocess. So the quickest solution (without learning how to properly handle processes) is to set sleep timer:

```
import time

tts = gTTS(text=m, lang='en')
tts.save("greeting.mp3")
p = vlc.MediaPlayer("greeting.mp3")
p.play()
time.sleep(120) # number of seconds in
```

However, there is this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6037997/3612149) for finding the length of media so the sleep period can be set from code.